# Metrizable Countable Compactness implies Compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I've read the other posts regarding this question but they all use obscure lemmas and other equivalences of compactness to prove their point. I want to start with countable compactness and metrizability and work toward compactness, using these assumptions alone. My proof is below.

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a countably compact metric space. Let $\mathscr{U} = \{U_\gamma\}_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ be an open cover of $X$. Now, suppose the collection $\mathscr{A} = \{B_d(x_i,q): i \in \mathbb{N}, q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ covers $X$. Since $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable, then $\mathscr{A}$ is countable.

Since $\mathscr{A}$ is countable, there are finitely many $x_1,\dots, x_n \in X$ so that the collection $\mathscr{A}_0 = \{B_d(x_i, q): 1 \leq i \leq n, q \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ covers $X$.

Consider the collection of all intersections of members of $\mathscr{A}_0$ and $\mathscr{U}$, $ \mathscr{U}_0 = \{B_d(x_i,q) \cap U_\gamma\}$. Then $\mathscr{U}_0$ is a finite subcover of $\mathscr{U}$ and so $X$ is compact.

The only issue is that $\mathscr{U}_0$ is not actually finite, although the finite number of open balls seems to make $\mathscr{U}_0$ like "quasi-finite" in a certain sense. I think I'm close but I'm not quite there. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: I have a weird *de ja vu* feeling. Didn't you post the question before? Anyways, to complete the proof, you take the $x_i$ from a countable dense subset. The existence of such a subset follows from the space being totally bounded, which follows easily from countable compactness.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I’m also feeling de ja vu.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I see. How does this take care of the potentially infinite number of $U_\gamma$'s in $\mathscr{U}$ though?

Comment: Each $U_\gamma$ is a union of open balls with center from the countable dense set and rational radius. You can then, basically, treat $X$ as covered by elements of this countable family. Take a finite subcover consisting of such balls and note that each of the finitely many balls is contained in some $U_\gamma$. What about the de ja vu?